# Can't create SQL database, visual studio gets stuck and I get this error after a while

Tags: sql-server, visual-web-developer-2010

[image]

It says "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error:26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

I tried looking up solutions online but I couldn't find anything.

I am using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. I'm not using anything new because that's what my school uses when teaching. I've tried creating another website and doing it there, it gave me the same error.

Comment: In SQL server, did you allow remote connections?

Answer (score 0):

Let us check into the steps to resolve this error.

1. SQL Server should be up and running.

2. Enable TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration
3. Open Port in Windows Firewall
4. Enable Remote Connection
5. Enable SQL Server Browser Service

   https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/ read this article to doing steps I described

Comment: In every tutorial I saw of people doing this they just clicked add new item, chose SQL database and it worked, are you sure I need to do all this before it will work? I don't even have an SQL server and they didn't either.

Answer (score 0):

The installation should have included an instance of SQL Server Express Edition.  Verify that you have that installed and running.

Comment: I do, or at least it says that over here: https://imgur.com/a/19S7M7N

Comment: It looks like it's not a default instance and the instance name is not SQLEXPRESS, so you'll have to specify it in the connection string.